# Adding extra bits in c bitfield

Tags: c

I have to update the following structure to add street information in the structure.

```
typedef struct address_tag {
    union {
        struct {
            unsigned state   : 20;     
            unsigned city    : 10; 
            unsigned unused :2;
        };

        uint32_t address;
    };

} defect_address_t;
```

I used the unused bits and used 2 bits for street:

```
typedef struct address_tag {
    union {
        struct {
            unsigned state   : 20;     
            unsigned city    : 10; 
            unsigned street :2;
        };

        uint32_t address;
    };

}address_t;
```

The problem is I have to reserve 10 bits for street instead of 2. Is there a way I can add do it? I have to make sure the address is 32 bits.

Comment: 20+10+10 = 40. can't do it unless you lose bits from elsewhere, or increase your allowable size...

Comment: Why do you need 20 bits to identify a state? That's more than 1 million possibilities.

Comment: So you're assuming there are no more than 1024 streets within a city? I'm not saying you shouldn't (and I don't know how many streets a city can have), but the assumption should be explicit.

Comment: Agreed that you should only need 6-bits for states - if this is the US.  That gives you 14 bits back to work with...

Comment: How little RAM do you have that you don't have another 4 bytes to spare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution is to take some bits from others, such as `state`. If you are US only, you need no more than 6 bits for the state. You would likely need some bits from state in the city field, anyway.

However, if your only concern is memory (occupying no more than 32 bits), you can just add all the possibilities to an `enum`, and have functions that extract the state/city/street.

```
typedef enum state_city_street_t
{
    CALIFORNIA,
    CALIFORNIA_SANFRANCISCO = CALIFORNIA,
    CALIFORNIA_SANFRANCISCO_MISSIONSTREET = CALIFORNIA_SANFRANCISCO,
    CALIFORNIA_SANFRANCISCO_HOWARDSTREET,
    CALIFORNIA_SANFRANCISCO_END,
    CALIFORNIA_MOUNTAINVIEW = CALIFORNIA_SANFRANCISCO_END,
    CALIFORNIA_MOUNTAINVIEW_CASTROSTREET = CALIFORNIA_MOUNTAINVIEW,
    ...
    CALIFORNIA_END,
    NEVADA = CALIFORNIA_END,
    NEVADA_LASVEGAS = NEVADA,
    NEVADA_LASVEGAS_THESTRIP = NEVADA_LASVEGAS,
    ...
} state_city_street_t;

#define GET_CONST(state, city, street) state##_##city##_##street
#define IS_STATE(value, state) ((value >= state) && (value < state##_END))
```

This guarantees the best memory usage (no combination of bits is wasted). The main tradeoff being harder access of individual fields, both in terms of performance and code clarity. Ideally, the enum would be autogenerated.